# Yii2 advanced два поддомена?

Tags: yii2

Объясните как правильно сделать два поддомена?

```
site.ru

структура
backend
---web
frontend
---web
pit
---web
```

Еще нужно, чтобы было так site.ru, admin.site, pit.site.ru.

Comment: А что если нету доступа к Apache.
Как настроить на хостинге?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Копируй любую папку backend или frontend и называй как тебе нужно.

Я к примеру скопировал backend и назвал api.

Внутри папки api - в каждом классе нужно поменять namespace backend на api.
Так же в api/config/main.php поменять везде backend на api.

Далее в common/config/bootstrap.php 
добавляешь алиас

```
Yii::setAlias('@api', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/api');
```

Собственно это всё, дальше уже в apache или nginx указываешь virtualhost к этой папке и указываешь ей алиас к примеру так:

`//пример для Apache`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName api.site.ru
        DocumentRoot /var/www/yii/api/web
        <Directory /var/www/yii/api/web>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Обращаясь к api.site.ru 
Веб-сервер поймет что нужно пойти в api/web/index.php и запустит его.

Comment: и тогда я получу себе такой поддомен pit.site.ru, я правильно Вас понял???

Comment: если веб сервер настроишь, чтобы он перенаправлял запросы на эту папку - да

Comment: Добрый день а не подскажите, как реализовать yii2 basic, я повторил с настройками с apache2, но почему то не тот компот.
если делать так site.ru/pit то работает, а если так pit.site.ru, то нет..... не подскажите в чем может быть причина?

Comment: yii2 basic это сайт (чисто фронт), по сути сделав на основе неё придешь к версии yii2 advanced)  поэтому надо смотреть что у тебя с настройками вебсервера, скорее всего там неверно настроил